# How to get user application (not processes) information in Windows using Python

Tags: python, process, taskmanager

I'm trying to obtain the information about the applications launched by the user in a Windows device. My idea is to obtain the same information that the Task Manager shows abount Apps, like RAM, CPU and Disk usage.
However, I can only find libraries that provide information about all the running processes, such as *tasklist*, *wmi* or *psutil*, and not only about the applications launched by the user. I also tried any way to differentiate background proceses from user applications, but I found nothing.

Is there any way to obtain the information above mentioned only about user applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in these things, but perhaps you would be interested in `win32com`, `win32gui`, or `win32api` and perhaps others. As I know these are very low level modules that allow you to interact with stuff like that. Here is a short script I made to force a certain window to remain on top of my screen even if I click on another window:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Snipping Tool')
print(hwnd)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 200, 200, 425, 325, 0)
```